# Как лучше сделать, чтобы после паролей не выводился None?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Если без костылей, то код таков, но в конце выводится None(в return я записал '?' потому что не знаю что туда написать чтобы None не было).

```
from random import sample
from string import ascii_letters, digits
# программа для генерации паролей определённой длинны определённое количество раз
def generate_password(length): # генерация паролей длины m
    symbols = list((set(ascii_letters) | set(digits)) - set('lI1oO0'))
    password = sample(symbols, length)
    return ''.join(password)

def generate_passwords(count, length): # вывод n паролей длины m
    for password in range(count):
        print(generate_password(length))
    return ?

n, m = int(input()), int(input())
print(generate_passwords(n, m))
```

Либо же можно немного переделать вторую функцию, мне кажется это делает код менее читаемым, можно ли как-то реализовать то же самое, но без подобных изменений?

```
def generate_passwords(count, length):
    for password in range(count - 1):
        print(generate_password(length))
    return generate_password(length)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `generate_passwords()` выводит на экран пароли (что означает, что у нее название, не соответствующее смыслу).

Вызов функции `generate_passwords()` в инструкции `print(generate_passwords())` выводит на экран результат выполнения функции `generate_passwords()`. Результат выполнения - это то, что функция возвращает. В питоне, если в функции отсутствует `return`, то она по умолчанию возвращает `None`. Именно этот None и печатается в строчке `print(generate_passwords(n, m))`.

В `return ...` можно было бы написать что угодно, но это не решило бы проблемы, потому что тогда выводилось бы не `None`, а то, что там написано.

Answer (score 1):

Убери print в конце

```
....
n, m = int(input()), int(input())
generate_passwords(n, m)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, запомню на будущее